# onclick javascript no longer applies to _GET php form value

Tags: php, javascript

I had a hardcoded form element that triggered a calculation function like this:

```
<input type="radio"  name="selectedaverageage" value="5-9" onclick="calculateTotal()" />5-9 Years
```

I've since captured the value from a previous form but the calculateTotal() no longer functions.

I tried to put the function in the body onload event but it did not work.

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked"  name="selectedaverageage" value="<?php echo $_GET['age']; ?>" onclick="calculateTotal()" /><?php echo $_GET['age']; ?>
```

How do I call calculateTotal() now that I no longer have to click on a radio button?

Comment: You'll need to show the function.

Comment: Depending on how you have your calculateTotal getting the variables, just call it at the bottom of the page so that it will run when the page loads.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what that function does ? Do you actually have a golden badge ? :O

Comment: Why do I need to show the function?  I just need a way to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put this on the next line under your radio button.

```
<script>calculateTotal.apply(document.getElementsByName('selectedaverageage')[0])</script>
```

Comment: I need to make sure the calculateTotal runs based on the name="selectedaverageage" of the form element.